# disnake (discord.py works also.. or not, depends) postgreSQL setprefix command

Tags: python, postgresql, discord, discord.py

i'm currently hardstuck in a maybe easy situation... my `!setprefix<prefix>` won't do anything. it's just empt. When i insert a `print(DEFAULT_PREFIX)` in any of this code, it will print the set default of "!". Even in my postgreSQL db, the default is set to "!". (rechecked with deleting and restarting everything)
I bet it has something to do with my bot.db which is set in main.py.

my main.py

```
*
from cogs.prefix import getprefix



async def create_db_pool():
    bot.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="**", user="**", password="**")
    print("Database connected succesfully") #placeholder, is set correctly in my code


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=getprefix, help_command=None, intents=intents,
                   activity=activity, status=disnake.Status.idle)


* 

bot.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

my prefix.py (as cog)

```
from disnake.ext import commands

DEFAULT_PREFIX = '!'


async def getprefix(ctx, message):
    if not message.guild:
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(DEFAULT_PREFIX)(ctx, message)

    prefix = await ctx.db.fetch('SELECT prefix FROM prefixes WHERE guild_id = $1', message.guild.id)
    if len(prefix) == 0:
        await ctx.db.execute('INSERT INTO prefixes(guild_id, prefix) VALUES ($1, $2)', message.guild.id, DEFAULT_PREFIX)
        prefix = DEFAULT_PREFIX
    else:
        prefix = prefix[0].get("prefix")
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(ctx, message)


class Prefix(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def setprefix(ctx, newprefix):
        await ctx.db.execute('UPDATE prefixes SET prefix = $1 WHERE guild_id = $2', newprefix, ctx.guild.id)
        await ctx.send("Updated to prefix by!")

    @setprefix.error
    async def setprefix_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("You can't do that!")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Prefix(bot))
```

Comment: I just get random downvotes? :D Just tell my what i'm missing or could do better. I'm still learning, just downvoting is like "yeah, this is **** but i won't help you to get better".

Comment: I didn't see your call to the `setup(bot)` function of `prefix.py` in `main.py`. This way the cog `Prefix` is not being inserted into the bot.

Comment: main.py:
https://sourceb.in/k8jo8i272l

prefix.py:
https://sourceb.in/0ofz6Bxs4y

stack just told me "too much code" so i reduced it. But i think wuth this pasted code in the links. it should be easier to get my full steps

Comment: Is your `setprefix` command running without error and responding properly?

Comment: Nah, it did nothing. I fugured it out now while deep debbuging every single line, literally noone could help me. But I knew it was something wuth `getprefix` so i moved it back to my `main.py` and.. it worked. it was due my (changed it now)
`await ctx.db.execute('UPDATE prefixes SET prefix = $1 WHERE guild_id = $2', newprefix, ctx.guild.id)`
in `setprefix` and the referenced `bot.db` in my `getprefix()`
but i could not just import something out of the `main.py` and reimport it right after. So i reorganized my complete code without splitting any function that needed in main.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a long debugging run i finally got my problem. It was due my `getprefix()` function could not resolve `bot.db` and just importing leads to other problems.

So i simply moved the whole `getprefix()` function into `main.py` and changed in `prefix.py` `ctx.db.execute(*)` into `self.bot.db.execute(*)` and voila, it works. That costs me a lot of headache and was the thing that i had to be pointed out. Maaybe this will help any other guy stucked at this point where organizing gone wrong.